# free equity screeners with export to excel

Tags: equities, excel

I am having a tough time finding a free equity screener that allows me to download the following data into excel: P/E or EV/EBITDA, Growth, Return on capital or any return measures would be helpful. Any ideas? thanks so much!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

[Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/) requires a premium account to download their statistics, but often they offer a free trial.

Answer (score 0):

FINVIZ.com offers about a dozen screeners.  The **Valuation** screener might be of interest to you.   Unfortunately, it's 382 pages so you'll either need a clever way to capture them or you'll have to subscribe for at least a month in order to export the data.  I offer no assurance that the data is accurate.

Comment: Second Finviz, well worth it.